# How can I track HTML 5 video download clicks in browser player?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

How to capture HTML 5 Video element download event

I want to add some analytics on clicking of download.
I am using Using simple video tag in html that is playing in browser player.

```
<video
    src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg"
    width="320"
    height="240"
    controls
    id="myVid"
>
```

[image]

Comment: This task should probably be handled by code running on the server which responds with the video resource — you can define a unique "download" endpoint by discriminating the URL (e.g. using a [query parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Web_mechanics/What_is_a_URL#parameters)). If the objective is to initiate a local download of already-cached video data (e.g. from a blob URL) and track that action, then a custom download button will need to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

There is no download event in the HTML5 media api specs - see the latest working specs here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#mediaevents

To count the downloads, you can do this server side as suggested by @jsejcksn in the comments.

Alternatively, if you need to do it client side, you can define your own custom controls and add some analytics triggers to the code that handles the download button. In fact not all browsers support a download button, as it is not mandatory in the specs, so you may want to add it as a custom control anyway.